# React : Lock focus to input until move away manually?

Tags: reactjs

There's an input element in my page, and I use the input to add new items to the page. I want the focus to be always in the input element, so I can type => press enter to add => type another ...

However, the page rerenders everytime the new item got added.

I've tried

```js
const handleAdd = () => {
  if (value) {
    // process the value
    // ...

    setValue("");
    inputRef.current?.focus();
  }
};
```

But when I `console.log(document.activeElement)`, it first prints out the input, but then the focus goes to `body` element.

Is there any way to keep the focus in the input? Until I click away?

Answer (score 0):

Add an OnBlur to reset the focus

```
const inputRef = useRef(null);


return (<>
   <input ref={inputRef} onBlur={() => inputRef.current.focus()} />
</>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Method1:* Add the `autoFocus` attribute to the `input` element.

*Method2:* Set the autofocus manually inside `useEffect` in order to set the input focus after the page is rendered again.

*Method3:* Just like your code, when the user presses enter, then set the focus again inside the function.